# SecurityException: getSerial: The user 10134 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, securityexception

I want to get the Build.getSerial() from the Android phone. Up to Android O i needed the Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission. However in Android 10 i get the above exception.
What i did is added this permission to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

And in the activity i need to request for the permission but there is not such a permission

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@ListActivity, 
   arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, 
   <<Manifest.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE>>), 
   SERIAL_NUMBER_PERMISSION)
```

So how can i get the serial Number if i cannot Grant the permission..? What should i do?

Answer (score 9):

Refer the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids):

> Caution: Third-party apps installed from the Google Play Store cannot declare privileged permissions.

As such only google apps and phone manufacturer apps (or if you are device admin or owner app) can access previleged permissions

Comment: so whats the solution?

Comment: Google has not given any solution yet. It's worse than "Dangerous permissions" - You cannot even ask user to grant a permission at all!

Answer (score 0):

if you just need a unique ID, and don't mind it's unique for devices, users, and APK keys, just use

```
android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: I want it to be unique for each device

Comment: the scuttlebutt is that the ID you get from `adb devices -l` is "insecure," so you are not allowed from inside the app to see it. El Goog has no fix for this, such as a token with one-way encryption